# SBCL forward declaration: possible?

Tags: forward-declaration, sbcl

I'm writing some code in SBCL, and the ordering of my functions keeps causing warnings of the following type to appear when I load files into the REPL:

```
;caught STYLE-WARNING:
    undefined function: FOO
```

Where `FOO` is the symbol for the function. This is purely due to how they are ordered in my file, as the function `FOO` *is* defined, just not before the part of the code that throws that warning.

Now, in Clojure, which is the Lisp I'm familiar with, I have the `declare` form, which lets me make forward declarations to avoid this kind of issue. Is there something similar for SBCL/Common Lisp in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I found in the manual, section 4.1.1:

```
CL-USER> (defun foo (x) (bar x))
; in: DEFUN FOO
;     (BAR X)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: BAR
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     BAR
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
FOO
CL-USER> (declaim (sb-ext:muffle-conditions style-warning))
; No value
CL-USER> (defun baz (y) (quux y))
BAZ
```

So you can at least silence the style warnings.

I also thought about how SBCL is handling the evaluation step in the REPL: it compiles the code. So I restarted the inferior lisp process and ran "compile region" on the following two lines:

```
(defun foo (x) (bar x))
(defun bar (y) (baz y))
```

and SBCL only complained about `baz`, but not about `bar`. Are you giving single functions to SBCL or larger chunks?

Comment: I typically load the whole file using ``(load "foo.lisp")`` at the toplevel. These warnings show up the first time I load a new file.

Comment: Try `(compile-file "foo.lisp")` followed by `(load "foo.fasl")`. If you're running emacs/slime as frontend, Ctrl-c Ctrl-k does this for you.

Answer (score 6):

We can use the '(declaim (ftype ...))' for that:

```
(declaim (ftype (function (integer list) t) ith))

(defun foo (xs)
  (ith 0 xs))

(defun ith (n xs)
  (nth n xs))
```

Both the function 'foo' and 'ith' works fine and there is not any style warning about that.

http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_ftype.htm